# Delayed (dynamic) loading of framework(or dylib) on Mac

Tags: macos, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to load a framework (or dylib) on mac where I know the path only at runtime.

Windows solution:

- Link library with /DELAYLOAD
- Just before a function from the library is used, change the current directory in the program to the directory where the dll resides
- Call some function from this library. The dll is loaded from the current directory

On mac, I can use weak linking to make the application startup without the library being available yet. However, as soon as some function from the library is needed, I get "image not found", and the application is aborted.

How can I tell the Mac dynamic linker during runtime where to look for the library? "dlopen" does  not work, since it only loads the library and does not resolve the symbols. Setting rpath to "." (the current directory) and changing the current directory does not work. Setting typical environment variables (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) only works when done before running the executable, not during runtime.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper script or executable that discovers the path at runtime, add the path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, then calls `execve` to the real executable.

Answer (score -2):

Use dlopen() to open the library and then dlsym() to find the symbols. If you are relying on the dynamic linker, you must know the path in advance and set it either via the rpath or with environment variables. The rpath can take relative paths, so that may work for you... but most likely, dlopen() and friends is the best solution here (although it may take some work to convert to using function pointers).

The advantage of dlopen() etc, is the same (or similar) code will work on other *nix's.

You can also look at NSAddImage(), which is OSX specific but should also do what you want.

Comment: As mentioned, dlopen and dlsym are not what I'm looking for since I'd have to rewrite all the code. Very cumbersome for c++ classes. Also, rpath does not work since I cannot change it during runtime. I didn't know NSAddImage. Will it link the symbols correctly to the already loaded but lazily linked symbols used in the code?